# Python- IP address module

Tags: python

I have python 2.7 installed. I installed `pip install py2-ipaddress`. Ran the following in powershell. The issue is `No Output`

```
import ipaddress
def ipEntered():
    while True:
        try:
            val = input("Please enter the ip address of the server you wish to connect with:")
            return ipaddress.ip_address(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid IP address")
```

Comment: That script indeed does not produce any output. Did you mean to call `ipEntered()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program runs fine. Can you share the example on which it is failing ? I used the following code to test it out.

```
import ipaddress
def ipEntered():
        while True:
                try:
                        val = raw_input()
                        return ipaddress.ip_address(val)
                except ValueError:
                        print ("Invalid")

print ipEntered()
```

Comment: See image: https://ibb.co/daKi1w  . With the code above, nothing happens when I execute it.

Comment: You have to provide input. Try providing input like 127.0.0.1